# Conditional Formula for excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to do addition/subtraction from a total of one column, based on the value of a different column.

Here are the details:

Column H2:H61 has 3 possible values: `Complete`, `Incomplete`, `Does Not exist`.
Column I2:I61 are integers.

What I'm trying to accomplish is, for each Row in column H, evaluate if the value is "Complete". If it is, then, in a running total cell, convert the corresponding Row in I to a negative number and add it to the total. If it isn't, leave the number a positive number and add it to the total.

Example:

```
H2 = "Complete" I2 = 1.5
h3 = "Incomplete" I3 = 0.5
h4 = "Complete" I4 = 2.0
```

The total is 3

**EDIT**

Here is the full scope of it:

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgzZS.png)

So, the total values of I and L is currently 40.

What I'm trying to do is, for example, if H2 = "Complete", then I want to subtract I2 (which is 1.5), which would change the total value to 38.5.

H3 is "Does Not Exist" and != "Complete", so the total would still be 38.5.
H4 is "Complete", so the total would be 37.5

so on and so forth. Hope this helps clarify for everyone!

Comment: "...for each Row...evaluate if the value is 'Complete'". ...What do you mean if the row's value is "Complete"? If *any cell* in that row is `Complete`? If every cell in the row is `Complete`?

Comment: Please clarify with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
What I did was in a separate cell I made the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(H2:H61,"Completed",I2:I61)
```

From there, I used that cell to create the following formula to get the result I wanted:

```
=P31 - (S30+S31)
```

The S30 and S31 cells are there because I was counting for each "completed" value in two separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula in `K2` cell then drag and down.

```
=SUMIF($H$2:$H2,"Complete",$I$2:$I2)-SUMIF($H$2:$H2,"Incomplete",$I$2:$I2)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like the right answer, but doesn't account for the "Does not exist" option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like:

```
=40-SUMIF(H:H,"Completed",I:I)
```

assuming you do not have the `40` total in either Column H or I.